# Selecting only parallel lines along center line?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, select-by-location, parallel-lines

I have read through [how to find close and parallel lines](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93787) but I am still looking for a simpler solution. Found several ArcGIS forums post on the topic but no answers there either.

Does a tool exist in ET GeoWizards, ArcToolbox, or QGIS that will select only parallel lines (with a given tolerance)?

[image]

Comment: Are you open to coding your own tool? This could be accomplished in arcpy, .NET, or python (if you want to use QGIS).

Comment: yes, interested in a QGIS solution coding a tool but my coding skills are novice.

Comment: You mention ArcGis Desktop, yet you talk about QGIS. I have answered this question once (and got a bounty for it) in ArcGis http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93787/how-to-find-close-and-parallel-lines - this wouldn't translate to QGIS as several of the operators are ArcGis only. Let me know where/why this isn't suitable and we should be able to get an ArcGis result that works for you.

Comment: I saw your solution (long list of code) in that thread and tried to use it in a few different places. I am somewhat code-challenged so forgive my ignorance. Can you please list the steps to implement your code solution?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify which single desktop GIS product you are using to try and do this, please?  Asking about more than one is effectively asking more than one question which goes against the [Tour].