# Finding duplicate geometries that are not identical using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I'm working with a few roads and trails datasets. There are some duplicate geometries that are not identical. See photos below.

[image]

[image]

I tried Find Identical with XY Tolerance, but it didn't seem to find most of these. I tried continuing to increase the XY tolerance, but I just got it finding parallel roads like the roads below.

[image]

I even tried planarizing the lines and just got a bunch of segments. I thought about trying to pull them out based on number of intersections, but I'm not even sure how to make that work.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap?

Comment: Perhaps your situation is similar to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93787/finding-close-and-parallel-lines-using-arcpy/99754#99754 number of intersections start with feature vertices to points (both ends) then buffer by a small amount (dissolving), multipart to single part on the buffer and spatial join the buffer and end points with a statistic of count - this is the number of lines that start or end inside the buffer. You could also try sliver polygons from the lines (shape_length >> shape_area, don't worry about the units it's the factor that's important).

Comment: What do you want to do? Find the almost identical lines? Delete one of them? Create an "average" line? Try Integrate tool

Comment: Buffer the lines by some amount, calculate overlap between buffers, if more than X% the lines are almost identical.