# Merging layers with similar, but slightly different, line paths

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm trying to combine two datasets to get a more complete view of stream networks, OpenStreetMap and the NationHydrographyDataset. NHD is more complete overall but OSM contains a few branches that NHD doesn't have.

NHD(blue):

[image: NHD in blue]

OSM(red):

[image: OSM in red]

I thought about just merging the two but the complication is that for the main stream/river bodies the paths are more or less the same but have some variance:

[image: path variability]

I tried a few methods I found for similar situations of overlapping but dissimilar lines but none really seemed to fit. The last thing I tried that got the closest was extracting the vertices of the NHD layer and getting the closest point in the OSM line but that falls apart when the one layer snakes naturally too close to the other layers branch. Here,the extra NHD(blue) branch is close to the compared OSM main body and the points get skewed:

[image: close paths]

Any suggestions on what a somewhat reliable method to A) Merge the two layers to create one 'master' layer that contains branches both layers have and B) Merge/consolidate the overlapping OSM/NHD main paths into one 'average' path? I'm only really concerned about the data quality of smaller streams, for example I don't care if a large river is all janky, but I am concerned about getting a roughly(~50ft?) accurate line for smaller streams/creeks that are near inhabited areas. Ideally this will be automated in Python but I'd like to test, iterate and visualize in QGIS.

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93787/finding-close-and-parallel-lines-using-arcpy/99754#99754 sound like a solution, even though the question is about ArcGIS it's the concept that's important. Although the pictures are nice your question is far too long, many people that could potentially answer the question will get discouraged at the length of your question; consider paraprasing your question.

Comment: I'm not sure there's going to be anything like a good automated solution. You may have to do a lot of manual editing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part about adding missing data from one line layer to another, this is how I have done something similar in the past:

1. Choose the data source that you think is most accurate, this is `ds1`.
2. Apply a buffer to `ds1`: `ds1_buffer`. The buffer distance to use is the maximum distance you think river digitizations of both sources can be apart to be judged as the same water course.
3. Erase/difference `ds1_buffer` from `ds2` to `ds2_diff_ds1`. This now contains the branches that are missing from `ds1`.
4. Snap the features in `ds2_diff_ds1` to `ds1`, using the buffer distance used in step 2. This results in `ds2_diff_ds1_snapped`.
5. Append `ds2_diff_ds1_snapped` to `ds1`.

Comment: Oh man that's sick, thanks so much. This gets me most of the way there. I was playing with all those tools and thought the solution was in buffering the lines but I couldn't put it all together. The only thing left is that some lines track very closely with the main streams but then jog off outside the buffer and i end up with a little hump after merging the diff. Are you aware of a way to 'associate' a line with one it overlaps with and expand the buffer to include the bump out? If I make the buffer any larger I risk clipping smaller branches. Attributes on each layer don't match.

Comment: Maybe you could add a check that a "missing branch" should have a minimal length and/or that it should touch the buffer with only one point?